# Create a reusable complex table component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am mainly a backend developer trying to do some React and I have the following question for you:

The website I’m working on has a lot of pages that are very similar between them. Most of them have one or two tables that also have pagination, filtering, sorting on some rows and row selection (there are some tables that do not have pagination or filtering or sorting or row selection). Parameters coming from the url should be allowed and applied to the filters (and thus to the first data fetch), selected rows have batch actions and the button shows at the top of the table, each row has buttons in the last column to do actions like edit, delete, etc. Also one final think that complicates all this a bit more is that some tables have cells that have more than just text, they can have icons to the left, rignt or have 2 lines of text.

The tables look something like this:

[image]

I created hooks to handle the query params, filters and pagination, which I thought was going to be enough but I still have a lot of duplication. In my components I have code similar to this:

```js
const [dataLoading, setDataLoading] = useState(false);
const [data, setData] = useState([]);

const {
  queryParams, clearQueryParams, setQueryParams,
} = useQuery();
const {
  filters, updateFilters, clearFilters,
} = useFilters(queryParams);
const {
  paging, setPaging, setPage, setRowsPerPage,
} = usePagination();

// A lot of funtions that use state (less than before though)
```

I thought of creating a Table component that contains all of this logic and receives the functions it needs via props, but there is also a problem which is that there are certain actions outside the table that can make the data dirty and a reload is required (like a new element is present on the list or an item was deleted for example).

What would be a good approach to solve this while making the code reusable (easy to read and simple is a huge plus)?

Do you think having one complex Table component is a good idea or is it better to have a PaginatedTable, FilterableTable (or maybe there is a way to nicely compose those)?

Thanks

Comment: I would start with separating your concerns of table logic from fetching logic. I would absolutely make a Table component and then maybe a ListTable component that is a wrapper for your Table but also handles fetching logic, exposing a refresh... etc. In general I like to reduce prop dependency, so id recommend different hooks to handle things like pagination, sorting, searching, tools... etc. this gives flexibility in a subscription model to what you need in a given instance

Comment: @JohnRuddell How would you expose a refresh in the table? sending a prop and using it as a dependency of the useEffect hook?

Comment: well like a loader hook can expose its load method. `const {data, loading, error, reload} = useMyDataLoader()`. whatever code processes the request, wrap it inside a function that you call and also expose